# Результат expt равен 1.0

Tags: математика, lisp

Здравствуйте. В autolisp требуется вычислить уравнение:

[image: ф]

Я написал небольшую функцию:

```
(defun func (a b x)
  (expt (+ a (- b (/ (cos x) (sin x)))) (/ 1 (abs x)))
)
```

В результате выполнения (func 1 2 3) выводит 1.0, хотя я вычислил еще в экселе и там должно быть 2,155529488
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Вы перевели `x` в радианы для тригонометрических функций `cos` и `sin`?

Comment: Нет, я думал на cos и sin подается сразу значение в радианах

Comment: Я так и написал. Проверьте, что вы передаете в эти функции значения угла именно в том формате, который они ожидают.

Comment: Ну, 3 вероятно радианы и есть... в autolisp деление по умолчанию не целочисленное ли?

Comment: Да, кстати, если ввести в формате (func 1.0 2.0 3.0), то выводит как надо. Вопрос можно закрывать, наверное. (не люблю этот лисп, но в универе заставляют его учить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в типах.

> (/ 1 (abs 3)) == (/ 1 3)

Деление с целочисленными аргументами даёт целочисленный результат - `1/3 = 0`

Проверьте:  `(func 1 2 3.0)`

Comment: Да уже писал это. Спасибо, но я чуть-чуть раньше это понял.